# Why does System.gc() recycle only one object in this code?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In the code below, only one object cleared from heap memory at runtime (by calling `System.gc()`). Why is only one object recycled?

```
 class A{
    A a;
    public A(A a){
      this.a=a;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
      A a1=null;
      A a2=new A(new A(null));
      A a3=new A(a2);
      a1=a3;
      a1.a=new A(null);
      a2.a=null;  //Line12
      System.gc();
    }
  }
```

Comment: How you findout that GC happened? I hope you are aware that System.gc() doesn't do GC as soon as call happens.

Comment: Try an draw yourself a picture of which variable is pointing to what object after every line of code is executed. Also it's entirely possible an object gets removed automatically by GC *before* you call `.gc();`

Comment: @Nambari I'm interested to know how the OP found out as well, but do note that the docs for System.gc() say that "when control returns from the method call, the virtual machine has made its best effort to recycle all discarded objects."  While it's possible that the best effort might not get the inaccessible object, in this case it would be surprising if it didn't catch it.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Agree, best effort will happen and some where in that documentation I think you will see a note like, don't use System.gc() also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, an object can be collected when it is accessible neither directly as the value of a variable nor indirectly because another accessible object has a reference to it.  Let's go through the lines of code a few at a time and look at what the object reference graph looks like over time.

```
  A a1=null;               // 1
  A a2=new A(new A(null)); // 2
  A a3=new A(a2);          // 3
  a1=a3;                   // 4
```

Line 1 doesn't do much, and we could even eliminate it and change line 4 to `A a1 = a3` without any different results.  Line 2 sets `a2`'s value to a reference to a new instance of `A`, call it α, whose `a` field is a reference to a second new instance of `A`, call it β.  Line 3 creates a new instance of `A`, call it γ, whose `a` field is a reference to α. Thus, all of α, β, and γ, are referenced.  Line 4 makes `a1`'s value a reference to γ.  Note that:

- α is directly accessible as `a2`, and indirectly accesssible as long as γ is accessible;
- β is indirectly accessible through α, as long as α is accessible; and
- γ is directly accessible as `a1` and `a3`.

[image: first memory state]

Next,

```
  a1.a=new A(null);        // 5
```

`a1.a = new A(null)` updates γ's `a` field to be a new instance of `A`, call it δ. Now:

- α is directly accessible as `a2`, and not indirectly accessible through anything else;
- β is indirectly accessible only through γ;
- γ is directly accessible as `a1` and `a3`; and
- δ is indirectly accessible only through α.

[image: second memory state]

Finally,

```
  a2.a=null;               // 6
```

Now the last remaining reference to β is removed.  There are still references to α, γ, and δ.

- α is directly accessible as `a2`;
- β is not accessible directly or indirectly at all;
- γ is directly accessible as `a1` and `a3`; and
- δ is indirectly accessible only through γ.

[image: final memory state]

Because β is not accessible at all, it is a candidate for garbage collection.  The javadoc for [`System.gc()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29) says:

> Runs the garbage collector. Calling this method suggests that the Java
>   virtual machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order
>   to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse.
>   When control returns from the method call, the virtual machine has
>   made its best effort to recycle all discarded objects.

Thus, when we get to

```
  System.gc(); // 7
```

the system *may*, but is not required to, collect β.  It's probably safe to assume that β would be collected by a “best effort to recycle all discarded objects,” but it's not a guarantee.

Comment: excelent explanation. Thank you very much. This diagram is all that i need to understand this problem. excelent !!

Answer (score 3):

I think it's horrid to try and pin exact GC-collection times in Java, but anyway ..

.. the Java garbage collection works on [*object reachability*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Reachability_of_an_object). If an *object* is strongly reachable - that is, if it can be accessed by any path from a reachability or known root, which includes local variables - then the object *cannot* be reclaimed<sup>1</sup>.

Consider this breakdown, where W, X, Y, Z represent different *instances* of A. The syntax I use to show any particular A is `instance {a-> instance}` where `a` refers to the member variable. Remember each `new` creates a *different* instance, and that assignment of object values does *not* create new objects (as such the *same Y object* - now shared by a1 and a3 - is modified during `a1.a=new A(null)` assignment).

```
  A a1=null;                // a1 = null
  A a2=new A(new A(null));  // a2 = W {a-> X}
  A a3=new A(a2);           // a3 = Y {a-> W}    
  a1=a3;                    // a1 = a3 = Y {a-> W}
  a1.a=new A(null);         // a1 = a3 = Y {a-> Z}
  a2.a=null;                // a2 = W {a-> null}
  System.gc();

  // Then:
  // a1 = a3 = Y {a-> Z}    (Expanding: Y {a-> Z {a-> null}})
  // a2 = W {a-> null}
```

So at the end the variables a1 and a3 - which are *reachability roots* - are "referencing" `Y {a->Z}` and a2 is "referencing" `W {a->null}`. This means that W, Y and Z are all still strongly reachable (Z is strongly reachable through Y) and not considered eligible for reclamation in Java-land<sup>2</sup>.

Only X is no longer reachable at the `System.gc()` line. However, this does *not* mean that X will be garbage collected, even with an explicit GC call - it only means that X is *eligible* to be reclaimed at some point in the future.

Of course, as soon as the function ends, all the local variables are no longer reachability roots and none of the A objects are strongly reachable making them all eligible :)

---

<sup>1</sup> Using object reachability to discuss a GC still works even when not using a traditional Mark & Sweep based approach (which is commonly found in JVMs) as the same rules apply to any correctly functioning GC system: if there is a chance an object *can* be accessed, it *cannot* be reclaimed. And conversely: if an object cannot be accessed, then it should be reclaimed.

<sup>2</sup> The rules to determine reachability roots differ by language/runtime. For instance, there are subtle differences with C#/CLRs handling in certain edge cases.

Comment: It may be helpful to factor weak references and finalizers into the mix: if an object can be accessed, the space it occupies be reclaimed, but if the only references to an object are weak ones, they should be invalidated [which would then allow any space used by the object to be reclaimed]. If the only rooted reference to the object is the system's list of objects that override `finalize`, the object should be moved from that list to a list of objects whose `Finalize` method should run ASAP. When `finalize` runs, it will be removed from that list and its space can probably be reclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the comments below:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  A a1=null;
  A a2=new A(new A(null));  //a2.a = new A(null); //line 3
  A a3=new A(a2);           //a3.a = a2
  a1=a3;                    //a1 = a3
  a1.a=new A(null);         //a1.a = a3.a = null; a2 is still referenced
  a2.a=null;  //Line12      //a2.a = null => object at line 3 is cleared after gc
                            //because it is not referenced anymore by any variable.
  System.gc();
}
```